# MySQL last_modified column that ignores updates on specific column?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a `updated_at` column that updates the timestamp whenever a change is made on the row. However, I would like it to ignore when changes are made on a specific column, `views`. Is this possible? The views column is constantly updated and is used as a showcase to see how many times the row has been publicly viewed.

Here is an example table;

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT NULL,
  views INT NULL,
  amount FLOAT NULL,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I then have a script that does: `views = (views+1)` essentially which would then trigger `updated_at` for that row.

Is it possible to keep `updated_at` while ignoring changes made on the `views` column?

Comment: It doesn't sound like'views' is something that would belong in this table

Comment: Yeah that is something I had considered, maybe moving it to an independent table would be the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a custom trigger with condition is easy solution for this problem, remove
ON UPDATE NOW(), and make a trigger to update this column if not view change

check columns with OLD.yourcolumn and NEW.yourcolumn ( sorry Im lazy to write complete solution)

operators will help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER customTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (conditons) THEN
      --type your statements here
   END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Custom trigger seems to be a good way forward. I'll test custom trigger and if I'm not happy with it then I will separate the views into a different table.

Comment: separate a custom table is a good choice, if you want this thing cause analitics I suggest google analitics ( or other thirdparty analytic ), you can make custom dashboard and and custom events too. If you want it to private you can make you own pixel follow code, this will be faster than you working with database things.